# Converting ee.Date object to client string in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, date

I'm trying to export all the images in an ImageCollection to Google Drive and by default name the output image with the date using **format()** function. However, when I try to name a export task by a date, the name in tasks is something like:

```
ee.String({ "type": "Invocation", "arguments": { "date": { "type": "Invocation", "arguments": { "value": { "type": "Invocation", "arguments": { "object": { "type": "ArgumentRef", "value": "_MAPPING_VAR_0_0" }, "property": "system:time_start" }, "functionName": "Element.get" } }, "functionName": "Date" }, "format": "YYYY-MM-DD" }, "functionName": "Date.format" })
```

Note the date values are gone and only some of the images are exported. Here's the link to [the code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8d51e4ac9f220ba1d1fa4d15efec4cf3)

All I need is only a formatted string from a date object.

Is there a simpler way to export an image collection?

Comment: `Export` is a client side function, while `map` is a server side funtion. What you want to achieve will only work if you create a client side loop (`for.. in...`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For loop do work in this case. GEE strongly recommend not to use the for loop, so maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: Avoiding loops is generally a good tactic to avoid inefficient operations. However, that mostly applies to stuff you want to calculate *within* GEE. The better question might be - why are you exporting Sentinel-2 Vegetation Index images, instead of performing your calculations completely within GEE and only export the final result?

Comment: I'm new to gee and trying to caculate a spatio-temopral version of Moran's I. But I don't know how to implement it in gee. Sunsetting images to a small region and test that index in Matlab is way faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Kersten commented, you should use a client side loop

```js
var size = S2VI.size().getInfo()
var S2VI_list = S2VI.toList(size)

for (var n=0; n<size; n++) {
  var image = ee.Image(S2VI_list.get(n))
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  date = date.getInfo();
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: date,
    fileNamePrefix: date, // this is the name actually
    folder: 'EE Outputs',
    scale: 20,
    region: XiangJiang,
    maxPixels: 130000000000,
  })
};
```